# Understanding Thread Indexing in cuda :

Tags: cuda

Consider the Following Kernels :

1. Multiple Threads Single Block :

```
   __global__ Kernel(){
             int tid = threadIdx.x;
          }
```

2. Multiple Blocks Multiple Threads :

```
    __global__ Kernel(){
         int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x* blockDim.x;
        }
```

3. Block Stride

```
    __global__ Kernel(int n){
           for(int tid = threadIdx.x; tid < n; tid += blockDim.x){
           }
        }
```

4. Grid Stride

```
    __global__ Kernel(int n){
           for(int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x; tid < n; tid += blockDim.x * grdiDim.x){
           }
        }
```

Now **1** will launch requested number of threads from a single block but the maximium number of threads is limited to 1024 (my hardware).Just spawn off another block.

**2** Launches requested number of threads from multiple blocks. Now the Maximum Number of threads that can be launched is now increased to 65535 * 1024.

**3** is a block-stride loop and **4** is a grid stride loop.

What I don't understand is how does **3** and **4** iterate ? Few articles I read state grid-stride loops iterate over batches, what does this mean ?

Output from **3** when called executed as Kernel<<<(4000 + 1023)/1024,1024>>>(4000) :

```
Local Thread Id : 56  Block ID : 2 Global Thread Id : 3128
Local Thread Id : 57  Block ID : 2 Global Thread Id : 3129
Local Thread Id : 58  Block ID : 2 Global Thread Id : 3130
Local Thread Id : 59  Block ID : 2 Global Thread Id : 3131
Local Thread Id : 60  Block ID : 2 Global Thread Id : 3132
Local Thread Id : 61  Block ID : 2 Global Thread Id : 3133
Local Thread Id : 62  Block ID : 2 Global Thread Id : 3134
Local Thread Id : 63  Block ID : 2 Global Thread Id : 3135
Local Thread Id : 448  Block ID : 3 Global Thread Id : 3520
Local Thread Id : 449  Block ID : 3 Global Thread Id : 3521
Local Thread Id : 450  Block ID : 3 Global Thread Id : 3522
Local Thread Id : 451  Block ID : 3 Global Thread Id : 3523
Local Thread Id : 452  Block ID : 3 Global Thread Id : 3524
Local Thread Id : 453  Block ID : 3 Global Thread Id : 3525
Local Thread Id : 454  Block ID : 3 Global Thread Id : 3526
Local Thread Id : 455  Block ID : 3 Global Thread Id : 3527
Local Thread Id : 456  Block ID : 3 Global Thread Id : 3528
```

Sometimes the switch occurs between 0,1,2,3 blockIdx.x but sometimes it just switches back and
forth between 2 and 3 ?

> By using a loop with stride equal to the grid size, we ensure that all addressing within warps is unit-stride, so we get maximum memory coalescing, just as in the monolithic version.

What does this mean ?

Source : https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is not useful, as there is no guarantee for which block will be scheduled at which point in time on which streaming multiprocessor (SMP). Even the warps inside the same block do not have to run in parallel. So probably one warp of block 2 and one warp of block 3 are processed in parallel on different SMPs. It seems that you should first try to understand [memory coalescing](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/).

All these examples expect you to access global memory as `array[tid]`. So using 1. or 3. with more than one block without using the block index at all would mean that multiple blocks are doing exactly the same work. So 2. and 4. are the more generic ones. With 2. You have to be careful to launch enough threads for your problem size (e.g. size of `array`), while the grid stride loop in 4. makes sure that you will get the right result, even if you launch less threads. But you might not get the full performance if there are not enough blocks to fill the GPU.

The point to understand is that each block is made up of warps (up to now of a size of 32 lanes or "threads") which work similar to a SIMD vector lanes working on vector registers. The threads of a warp normally work in lockstep, such that loading a continuous region of memory cooperatively (lane 0 loads element 0, lane 1 loads element 1, ... lane 31 loads element 31) is much faster, as long as these elements aren't bigger than 8 byte.

Any two threads that do not belong to the same warp could run in any order (or in parallel). There are no guarantees.

How does it iterate? The for loop should make it pretty clear. `blockDim.x * grdiDim.x` is the total number of threads. If you use 3. with only one block, `blockDim.x` is the total number of threads. So instead of each thread working on a continuous chunk (for cache locality), as would be done on a CPU, the threads work in a interleaved fashion (for memory coalescing).

There are different ways to iterate and still preserve memory coalescing (e.g. each warp or each block processing a continuous chunk of memory), but this way is the easiest to write down and understand. Also, assuming that you do not use more threads than can be scheduled at once, the grid stride loop has in a way more "cache locality" than these other versions, at least when looking at the L2 cache which is shared by the SMPs.

Comment: with the grid stride loop , lets say i have array of 1 million elements and i launch a thousand threads so thread 0 will have tid of 0, 1000, 2000 and so on while thread 1 will have tid of 1, 1001, 2001 ... so these 1000 threads will iterate over 100 elements each ? Is this what makes threads independent of max thread count and only limitation would be the amount of data vram can allocate ?

Comment: 1e6 / 1000 = 1000 =/= 100 Other than that, yes.

Comment: By using [managed/unified memory](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/) you are not even limited by the amount of global memory as it will automatically use global memory kind of as a cache to the CPU RAM. Naturally this might come at a performance cost without any further optimization.

Comment: sorry forgot i wrote million, i meant 1 lakh,  anyway thanks !!